# How to Shim a Method with a ref Parameter in Microsoft Fakes for Unit Testing?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to perform unit testing using the Microsoft Fakes framework, but I've encountered an issue where I'm not sure how to handle a method with a ref parameter in the Shim syntax. I have an original method as follows:

```
namespace Test
{
    public class LogicCode
    {
        public Quote getQuote(ref string quoteId)
        {
            // Implementation of the original method
        }
    }
}
```

I'm attempting to shim this method using the Fakes framework, but I'm unsure of how to handle a method with a ref parameter within the following Shim syntax:

```
using (ShimsContext.Create())
{
    Test.Fakes.ShimLogicCode.getQuote = (【What should go here?】) => {
        // Implementation of our shim method
    }  
}
```

I need to know how to correctly handle this ref parameter in this scenario. Please help me understand what should be filled in that parameter so that I can successfully shim this method. Thank you!